# Can't get results from elasticsearch server using JS

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I guess the question says it all, but the thing is that there are some anomalies here :|

When javascript tries to fetch the search results I get this error:

```
Firefox(Firebug):    
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Chrome:
POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is a totally anticipated result, so I googled the solution and found it. 
So I added the following lines to the config:

```
http.cors.allow-origin: '*'
http.cors.enabled: true
```

And it kinda fixed the problem. Here's the strange part: The app is on a web server, which I access using, let's say, `http://whateverdomain.com`. So the origin of the javascript would be `http://whateverdomain.com` and not localhost, thus the problem. Well if that's the case, how come I can interact with elasticsearch, on the remote server, using [Sense](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sense-a-cool-json-aware-interface-to-elasticsearch) on my local machine? Isn't my global IP considered cross-origin????
It might be of importance to mention that in sense, i access the server using its IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I initialized elasticsearch-js, i used the default host, unchanged, which was localhost, and localhost on js means my local machine.
Changing that to my domain solved the problem.